# Scrapy command to extract specific fields of a web

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to create a dictionary on python using data froma  web written on json format. I am trying to use scrapy but nothing happens.

I have tried this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class my_spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "my_spider"

    start_urls = ["https://meteo.cat/observacions/llistat-xema"]

    def parse(self, response):

        for slug in response.xpath('//td[@headers="metacom"]'):
            yield {'title': slug.extract()}
if __name__ == "__main__":

    process = CrawlerProcess({
         'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
         'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {'s3': None},
         'LOG_ENABLED': True})

    process.crawl(my_spider) 

    process.start()

Any suggestion, plase?
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? For getting data from a single webpage `scrapy` might be overkill

Comment: I expect to obtain all the fields with this xpath //td[@headers="metacom"]. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you want the whole table in some form you can work with?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run the following:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# Remember to name class in camelcases.
class Myspider(Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    start_urls = ["https://meteo.cat/observacions/llistat-xema"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for slug in response.xpath('//td[@headers="metacom"]'):
            yield {'title': slug.extract()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {'s3': None},
        'LOG_ENABLED': True})

    process.crawl(Myspider)

    process.start()
```